# Moodle bulk user CSV import

Tags: csv, moodle

I'm trying to use a CSV a to bulk import users

```
username, firstname, lastname, email, idnumber, auth, country, city, institution, course1
a@b.ac.uk, a, z, a@b.ac.uk, a, LDAP, GB, London, B, B-A-STA
```

The the auth entry drops out saying,

```
LDAP
Auth plugin not supported here
```

but the other entries seem fine and the user gets added.  I can't seem to find documentation on adding auth types, how do I specify LDAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use CAS auth and always get a similar message, but users get added normally. I don't know if it is a bug...

Comment: the problem was using LDAP instead of ldap.  Using lower case still brings up an error, but the ldap connection is established. I should probably submit a patch to handle upper case!